# ¿Como colocar un codigo php dentro de un scrip en un archivo .php?

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

Tengo un proyecto de MVC y en mi archivo controlador tengo un case que me evaluá la acción que ejecuto, en la acción eliminar quiero colocar una alerta de SweerAlert que contenga un ok y un cancelar que cuando le de al botón ok lo elimine, antes de usar sweerAlert lo hacia normal pero sin preguntar, ahora que lo puse me da un erro de declaración de variable id en $trabajador->deleteById($id), le pondré el pedazo de código para que me ayuden porfavor.

```
  case "eliminar":
    {


        $alert ='<script>swal({
        title: "¿Estás seguro?",
        text: "Estás por borrar un registro, este no se podrá recuperar más adelante.",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Continuar",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, 
        function (isConfirm) {
            if(isConfirm){
                swal({
                    title: "Eliminado",
                    text: "Eliminaste el registro.",
                     showConfirmButton: false,
                    type: "error",
                    timer: 800


                }, function(){

                    '. $id= $_GET['id'] .';

                    '.$trabajador->deleteById($id).';

                    window.location.href="../Vista/trabajador.php?accion=actualizar";

            });


            }
            else{

                window.location.href="../Vista/trabajador.php";
            }
        });</script>';



        break;
    }
```

Comment: Enfocas mal el problema. Tu case "eliminar" va a `dibujar` un javascript. Por lo tanto, no puedes llamar a un metodo php de eliminar por id. Esto deberias hacerlo llamando desde ese javascript, por ajax, a una accion de tu php, pasandole el id.

Comment: Embeber código Php a JS es una mala práctica, el código es muy feo y difícil de mantener :S deberías reconsiderar tu lógica separando el front y el back de una mejor manera